# How to add dynamically FormControl in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting a set of question from API. Each question has question id.
How can I dynamically bind the question id to the `formControlName`?

Comment: If you tried something please post it here so we can help that way

Comment: i am getting this error - > Error: Cannot find control with path: 'project_form -> 1 -> f4ca07b0-a5fe-11e8-8311-e79475dba1d1'

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngFor inside your template and bind dynamic `formControlName`.

Template:

```
 <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  ...
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let question of questions">
      <input [formControlName]="questions.id">
    </li>
  </ul>
  ...
</form>
```

Component:

```
const questions = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]; // just for demo
this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
  questions.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.id]: '' }), {})
);
```

This will generate formGroup based on this object: `{1: "", 2: "", 3: ""}`. If you want, you can also set initial values to the form controls:

```
const questions = [{id: 1, value: 'q1'}, {id: 2, value: 'q2'}]; // just for demo
this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
  questions.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.id]: curr.value }), {})
);
```

Comment: i have done this in the same way but it is showing this error  i am getting this error - > Error: Cannot find control with path: 'project_form -> 1 -> f4ca07b0-a5fe-11e8-8311-e79475dba1d1 ................. i dont know why