# How can i add form controls using for loop dynamically in angular 7?

Tags: angular

i am struggling to create tables by prompting the user the number(n) of columns and then creating n form controls to prompt the column names.

the.html file is:

```
<form [formGroup] = 'formdata' (ngSubmit)="addTable(formdata.value)">
  <div>
    <label>Table Name:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName='name' placeholder="table name">
  </div>  
      <div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let number of numbers">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-1 ">Col{{number}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" formControlName='col{{number}}' placeholder="col{{number}}">
        </div>
      </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

but, the error here is

"ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'col0'
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'col1'
".

so, how can i add formControlNames in the .ts FormGroup using for loop? 
for example: col1: new FormControl(''), col2: new FormControl('') ... and so on

Comment: Sounds like you want a `FormArray`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add dynamically FormControl in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072961/how-to-add-dynamically-formcontrol-in-angular-6)

Comment: Have you tried `[formControlName]="'col' + number"`?

Comment: in the .html file it is ok. but the problem is in the .ts file. that is how to add form controls to my form group.  my form group is here:                                                                               
    this.formdata = new FormGroup({   name: new FormControl('') }).                         now i want to add col1: new FormControl(' ') using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use FormArray for this.

```
   <div class="form-group" formArrayName="products"
            *ngFor="let product of productSelForm['controls'].products['controls']; let i = index">
            <input id="sel_product{{i}}" type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" name="sel_product{{i}}">
            <label class="checkbox-custom" for="sel_product{{i}}"> {{products[i].name | translate}}
            </label>
          </div>
```